# PostgreSQL json field sum based on key and aggregate based on key value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Tried with some query loops but cannot extract with simple query sum of fields from array of jsons array objects.

Example of object in DB:

```json
[
    {
        "bars": [
            {
                "lot": None,
                "item_code": "S12L06",
                "quantity_kg": 164.1,
                "default_coil": False,
                "possible_bar": False,
                "wholesale_item": True,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 30,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 159.84
            },
            {
                "lot": None,
                "item_code": "S12L06",
                "quantity_kg": 164.1,
                "default_coil": False,
                "possible_bar": False,
                "wholesale_item": True,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 30,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 159.84
            }
        ],
        "coils": [
            {
                "lot": null,
                "item_code": "K10",
                "quantity_kg": 410.08288000000005,
                "default_coil": false,
                "possible_bar": false,
                "wholesale_item": false,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 134,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 397.68118
            },
            {
                "lot": None,
                "item_code": "S12L06",
                "quantity_kg": 164.1,
                "default_coil": False,
                "possible_bar": False,
                "wholesale_item": True,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 30,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 159.84
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "bars": [
            {
                "lot": None,
                "item_code": "S12L07",
                "quantity_kg": 164.1,
                "default_coil": False,
                "possible_bar": False,
                "wholesale_item": True,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 30,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 159.84
            },
            {
                "lot": None,
                "item_code": "S12L08",
                "quantity_kg": 164.1,
                "default_coil": False,
                "possible_bar": False,
                "wholesale_item": True,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 30,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 159.84
            }
        ],
        "coils": [
            {
                "lot": null,
                "item_code": "K14",
                "quantity_kg": 19.456799999999998,
                "default_coil": false,
                "possible_bar": false,
                "wholesale_item": false,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 8,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 18.74816
            },
            {
                "lot": null,
                "item_code": "K14",
                "quantity_kg": 19.456799999999998,
                "default_coil": false,
                "possible_bar": false,
                "wholesale_item": false,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 8,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 18.74816
            },
            {
                "lot": None,
                "item_code": "K13",
                "quantity_kg": 164.1,
                "default_coil": False,
                "possible_bar": False,
                "wholesale_item": True,
                "inventory_pieces_nets": 30,
                "inventory_quantity_kg": 159.84
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The output should be:

1. sum inventory_quantity_kg
2. sum pieces
3. grouped by item_code

Per **bars** and **coils**

Answer (score 0):

Using `jsonb_array_elements` with `cross join`:

```
select (v1 -> 'item_code')#>>'{}', sum(((v1 -> 'inventory_pieces_nets')#>>'{}')::float), 
   sum(((v1 -> 'inventory_quantity_kg')#>>'{}')::float) 
from tbl t cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.js) v 
cross join jsonb_each(v) t1 cross join jsonb_array_elements(t1.value) v1
group by (v1 -> 'item_code')#>>'{}'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rA-A0v7G)

Comment: ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar
filed is jsonb

Comment: select (v1 -> 'item_code')#>>'{}', sum(((v1 -> 'inventory_pieces_nets')#>>'{}')::float), 
   sum(((v1 -> 'inventory_quantity_kg')#>>'{}')::float) 
from warehouse_dispatchnote t cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.dispatch_calculations) v 
cross join jsonb_each(v) t1 cross join jsonb_array_elements(t1.value) v1
group by (v1 -> 'item_code')#>>'{}' limit 10